# Svn permission error on CentOS

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I installed svn and created my first repository on CentOS successfully. But i have some problems in configuration part. I can see the content in browser. I can checkout in Windows cmd but i cannot commit from Windows cmd. It gives svn E000013 error. When i google it, i realize that this problem is about permissions. i have a svn user named 'testusr'. I cannot give permission t this user, because it is not a linux user. I try apache, but it didnot work for me. Here some screenshot about my configuration. Can someone help me ?

**I fallowed this article:**

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion

**Permission:**

[image]

**Checkout is successull:**

[image]

**But commit crashed:**

[image]

**This is browser:**

[image]

Comment: there is one conf file related to svn, which allows to set user permission. check for conf file.

Comment: but i will work more than more repository and there will be N-N relation between repositores and users.

Comment: nope,In that config file you can mention like, for repository A (abc,xyz) are permitted to commit. for repo B (abc) is permitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solutıon for my problem. These codes fix it. Remember repos is my repository name.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/repos
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/wvn/repos
```